# Writing to file by creating further files (and not replacing/overwriting)

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

Is there any way to modify the following simple code, so that once the file `myBackup.csv` is created and the code is run over and over again, it doesn't just re-write the same file and destroy the previous contents, but creates further files?

```
string localPath = somePath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "myBackup.csv";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter( localPath );
sw.WriteLine( "blah blah:" );
foreach ( var element in entryId )
    sw.WriteLine( element );
localSaver.Close();
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. My mistake. I will edit the title immediately. I want further files, not over-writing on previous contents. Thank you for pointing this out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to check if the file exists and choose another file name if the file exists?

```
string localPath = somePath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "myBackup.csv";

int counter = 1;
while (File.Exists(localPath))
{
    localPath = somePath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "myBackup-" + counter + ".csv";

    counter++;
}
```

Then use `localPath` in your `StreamWriter` constructor.